# node.js readFile with size

Tags: javascript, node.js

in php i use

```
 $filename = "a.txt";
 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $heading = fread($handle, 4);
  fclose($handle);
  print $heading;
```

a.txt content

> hello every one

and the output its

> hell

now in node.js i use

```
fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('a.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
    });
```

its output

> hello every one

how can i use size length on node.js ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the length of the 'data' or do you want to only print 'hell' like in your php ??

Comment: only hell
..................
i can use substr did u think its good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "a.txt";

fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
  var buffer = new Buffer(4);
  fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 4, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
    var data = buffer.toString("ascii", 0, buffer.length);
    console.log(data);
    fs.close(fd);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

with: `data.substring(0,4);`